# Are these events independent or dependent? (Check my work)

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I'm studying for my exam, and unsure about my answers for these 3 practise questions:

[image: Questions]

My answers are as follow:

**Q1)** Independent, as can have HTH which satisfies B but not A.

**Q2)** Dependent, as the outcome of A affects B. Example if A is one head, then B is true.

**Q3)** Dependent, example: If B and C are satisfied, then A is not. Making A depend on B and C.

Overall, I don't think I understand the logic how to see if they are dependent or independent.

The exam will be multiple choice, so I don't need to prove or give formal reasoning, are there any tricks to figure out if events are dependent or independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1: $A:=\{THH, HHT, HHH\}, B:=\{HTH, THH, HHT, TTT\}, P(A|B)=P(\{THH,HHT\}|\{HTH, THH, HHT, TTT\})=\frac{2}{4} \neq P(A)=3/8$

so (1) is not independent, as A becomes more likely if we know B is true.

You just need to find one counterexample to the rule given by MPW above: P(A|B)=P(A) or $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$

Comment: P(A|B)={THH,HHT}=2/4≠P(A)=3/8, mind explaining this part please?

Comment: A = Two heads in a row, B = Even number of heads, there are only two outcomes in B that have two heads in a row, and there are 4 outcomes in B, so 2/4. However, there are three ways to get at least two heads in a row overall, and 8 possible outcomes from three coin flips, so 3/8.

Comment: If they were equal, will that make them independent?

Comment: @StackPWRequirmentsAreCrazy I've clarified my answer, as I breezed through a step.

Comment: Thank you, makes it much clearer. Say P(A) was somehow = 2/4, since it will be equal to P(A|B), would it be independent in that case?

Comment: @StackPWRequirmentsAreCrazy no, you need to have P(B|A)=P(B) and P(A|B)=P(A) if you are talking about two events. In general, independence is very onerous to prove from first principles because you have to check an ever-increasing set of 2-way, 3-way, ...n-way combinations, all of which must follow the multiplication rule for indpendent events....its a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you, was I correct with my other answers?

Comment: As @Did pointed out, none of your answers are in terms of probability, as mine was above. You need to either find a counterexample to the multiplication rule (as I have done) or show it holds for all pairwise combinations. Either way, you need to use probability statements, not vague statements about "affects"...that will not get you points with the teacher. Use my example as a template for the others...please try them yourself and see if you can verify/falsify that hypothesis that the probabilities multiply.

Comment: Thanks, for number 2 I did: P(A|B)=3/6 ≠ P(A)=3/8. Is my intuition correct?

Comment: Can you show your work? There are 4 ways to have *at most* 1 tail  in three tosses so P(A) is off

Comment: Looks like I did a dumb mistake, forgot TTT. Thank you!

Comment: @StackPWRequirmentsAreCrazy no problem, looks like you're able to set up the calculations now...just be sure to enumerate all outcomes that apply to that event :)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the definition of independence that events $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B)$? This is equivalent to the condition that $\Pr(A|B)=\Pr(A)$, and also to the condition that $\Pr(B|A)=\Pr(B)$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, Pr(A)Pr(B) is probability of A multiplied by probability of B, but what's Pr(A∩B)?

Answer (score 1):

Check the definition of the notion of independence and you will see that events are not independent *per se*, only with respect to some given probability measure. But none of your answers involves the underlying probability measure. Ergo.

Comment: Given the level of the practise questions in this post, I don't know if the OP will know measure theory yet...

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Not sure I understand your comment. It is a little difficult to imagine a solution without any occurrence of P(...). How would you call this mysterious object?

Comment: I think the measure is implied by the question, it is the counting measure on possible triplets. However, for intro stats, its a very intuitive measure and hence is not explicitly addressed. The post and questions make it clear that they are talking about counting triplets of binary elements.

Comment: I see what you mean though about the OP's answers. None are *reasons* why one is dependent or independent, which is what you were getting at, correct?

Comment: @Stack Did you downvote this, by any chance?

Comment: I did not. I will upvote it too :). I just did not understand probability measure, therefore did not reply.

Comment: OK. But what is it you read when there is some P (or Pr) in a solution?

Comment: @Did BTW: I did not downvote you either - not sure who did. Your explanation was correct, I just offered a comment on language. I think downvoting is not a very constructive form of feedback, so I rarely do it (as can be seen from my record)

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Thanks for the opinion. I try to downvote systematically wrong answers that are not corrected after the problem is signalled.